# tokenize string to string array

Tags: c#, regex, string

I would like to split the strings like `2x3y5z`, `4y`, `5x6y`, `7x4z` into separate strings:

```
 "2x3y5z" = { "2x", "3y", "5z" }
 "7x4z"= { "7x", "4z" }
```

My current solution involves `Substring` and `Replace` and looks quite convoluted. Is it possible to do this in RegEx in a much simpler way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are the rules to split the string? The following regexp assumes you have number from 0 to 9 and after that character from a to z.

```
        string pattern = @"[0-9]{1}[a-z]{1}";            
        var regexp = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern);

        var matches = regexp.Matches("2x3y5z");            

        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(match);
        }
```

Comment: If you can have more than one number before the letter, use this pattern: @"[0-9]+[a-z]{1}" or @"[0-9]{1,}[a-z]{1}"

Answer (score 0):

Provided you want to have groups consisting of a digit then a lowercase letter, cycle through your input with `\d[a-z]` and grab the matched text.